# String into Joda Period

Tags: jodatime

Is there a smart way to transform a String into a joda time period?

```
Period serviceAmountPeriod = new Period();
final Period p = serviceAmountPeriod.parse("87:33");
```

This does not work and I dont know how to use PeriodFormatter in this case.

[EDIT]

```
final PeriodFormatter dateFormat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes()
        .printZeroIfSupported().minimumPrintedDigits(2).toFormatter();
```

this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Similarly your edit,

After format with PeriodFormatter, you can parse your hours and minutes to Period.

```
    final PeriodFormatter dateFormat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes().toFormatter();
    Period period = dateFormat.parsePeriod("87:33");
    System.out.println("Period  =" + period);
```

And output is;

```
Period  =PT87H33M
```